# Select elements by their specific position from the nested list

Tags: list-manipulation

I am trying to solve a practical research problem, that is I need to select element in a specific position with the same offset, for example: select the second element in every three elements among the nested list: `{{a,b,c,1,2,3},{e,f,g,4,5,6},...}`, so in this example, we would get a new list: `{{b,2},{f,5},...}` so this example is a simple one, I want to implement this to broader problems such as manipulating nested list with larger dimensions. And the offset might be differ.

I was trying to use `Select` or `Part` to solve this problem.  Because for handling with 'position' stuff, `Part` works well. But both of them seems not support nested list manipulating that need to set an offset? Correct me if I were misunderstanding them please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
list = {{a, b, c, 1, 2, 3}, {e, f, g, 4, 5, 6}, ...};
list[[All, 2 ;; ;; 3]]
```

> ```
> {{b, 2}, {f, 5}, ...}
> ```

Comment: This one works great! Thanks for your help!