# Decomposing a list into certain structured nested list?

Tags: list-manipulation

Consider the below list

```
testlist = {0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 1, "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"}
```

I am trying to group every two numbers and every two letters in a list, and in the end form the following  result:

> reslist={{0, 1, a, b},{2, 0, c, d}, {0, 1, e, f}}

What I do is the following:

```
testmp= Partition[testlist, 2];
reslist = {};
 For[ii = 1, ii <= Length[testmp]/2, ii++,
  AppendTo[reslist, {testmp[[ii]], testmp[[ii + Length[testmp]/2]]}]
  ];
```

**Q: Is there simple way to do it?**
Furthermore, when the testlist is described by `CombineList` and gets larger, how one can efficiently do it? I find [some links](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/163166/55474) which potentially works but I failed to use it.

```
value = {{0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 2}, {0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 1}};
label = {{"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"}, {"a", "b", "d", "f", "c", "e"}};
CombineList = Array[Join[value[[#2]], label[[#]]] &, Length /@ {label, value}]
```

one example:

```
testlist={{0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 1, "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"}, {0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 1, 
  "a", "b", "d", "f", "c", "e"}}
```

the result could be something like the following

> { {{0, 1, a, b},{2, 0, c, d}, {0, 1, e, f}}, {{0, 1, a, b},{2, 0, d, f}, {0, 1, c, e}} }

Thank you!

Comment: This function will do what you need, for your `testlist` at least: `Flatten[TakeDrop[#, Length[#]/2] & @Partition[#, 2], {{2}, {1, 3}}] &`. You use it as e.g. `Flatten[TakeDrop[#, Length[#]/2] & @Partition[#, 2], {{2}, {1, 3}}] & @ testlist`.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin, thank you! that's a good solution for simple lists. does it also work for nested list? Or one have to do some for-loop things?

Comment: Simply `Map[function-above, your-nested-list]`.

Comment: thank you so much! that helps a lot!@LeonidShifrin

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
testlist = {{0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 1, "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"}, 
  {0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 1, "a", "b", "d", "f", "c", "e"}}

reShape1 = Join[##, 2] & @@ ArrayReshape[#, {2, 3, 2}] &;

Map[reShape1] @  testlist
```

> ```
>  {{{0, 1, "a", "b"}, {2, 0, "c", "d"}, {0, 1, "e", "f"}},
>   {{0, 1, "a", "b"}, {2, 0, "d", "f"}, {0, 1, "c", "e"}}}
> ```

Also

```
reShape2 = Join @@@ Transpose @ ArrayReshape[#, {2, 3, 2}] &;
reShape3 = Flatten[ArrayReshape[#, {2, 3, 2}], {{2}, {1, 3}}] &;
reShape4 = ArrayReshape[Transpose @ ArrayReshape[#, {2, 3, 2}], {3, 4}] &;
reShape5 = Transpose @ Fold[Transpose @* ArrayReshape, #, {{2, 3, 2}, {3, 4}}] &;

Equal @@ (Map[#] @ testlist & /@ 
  {reShape1, reShape2, reShape3, reShape4, reShape4})
```

> ```
>  True
> ```

Comment: This is a comment regarding the first suggestion you made. I am getting an error when I run the commands. If I use instead `reShape1@testlist` it gives the desired output

Comment: Thank you @DiSp0sablE_H3r0. I used  OP's second input list (also named `testlist`).

Comment: Thanks for clarifying and updating the answers. Excellent answer as always btw! +1 from me

Answer (score 4):

Here's a way that generalizes to lists of arbitrary length, provided that they are well-formed (with an even number of integer and string elements, and the same number of integer and string elements):

```
Catenate /@ 
 Transpose[
  SequenceCases[testlist, {Blank@#, Blank@#}] & /@ {Integer, String}],
(* {{0, 1, "a", "b"}, {2, 0, "c", "d"}, {0, 1, "e", "f"}} *)
```

Comment: nice way to create binary files, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

```
list = {0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 1, "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"};

SequenceCases[
  Transpose @ SplitBy[list, Head],
  x:{_, _} -> Catenate @ Transpose @ x]
```

{{0, 1, "a", "b"}, {2, 0, "c", "d"}, {0, 1, "e", "f"}}

Answer (score 2):

```
list = {0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 1, "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"};

Cases[Thread[Values[GroupBy[list, Head, Partition[#, 2] &]]], m_ :> Join @@ m]

(*{{0, 1, "a", "b"}, {2, 0, "c", "d"}, {0, 1, "e", "f"}}*)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
list = {0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 1, "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"};
c1 = Cases[list, _?NumericQ] // Flatten // Partition[#, UpTo[2]] &;
c2 = Cases[list, _String] // Flatten // Partition[#, UpTo[2]] &;
Flatten /@ Transpose[{c1, c2}]
```

---

> {{0, 1, "a", "b"}, {2, 0, "c", "d"}, {0, 1, "e", "f"}}